# Posting images & text to Timeline using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use the Facebook SDK or Graph API to create a post like the one below?

[image]

I essentially want to combine these two together:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] completionHandler:nil];
[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"Hello, World!" completionHandler:nil];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use following method :

```
// Present share dialog
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                 name:params.name
                              caption:params.caption
                          description:params.description
                              picture:params.picture
                          clientState:nil
                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                if(error) {
                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                  NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                                } else {
                                  // Success
                                  NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                }
                              }];
```

Here is the reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictionary setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) forKey:@"picture"];

        if (message) {
            [dictionary setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
        }
        FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:dictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        }];

        [connection start];
```